# Should we always sort an array before performing operations on it?

Tags: arrays, performance, sorting, time-complexity

So in a lot of cases when performing operations on the array, such as binary search, or set operations, sort array is always faster. For example, merging two sorted arrays take O(m+n) or O(n) for one variable, and two unsorted arrays take O(n^2). With its advantages, should we always sort an array before performing operations on it?

Comment: To say "always" would be absurd without specifying the operations you have in mind.  There are plenty of useful operations that are just O(n) and sorting is O(n log n).

Answer (score 1):

To *always* proactively sort will often make the proceeding operation faster, but you still spend the time and resources sorting the initial array.

If your logic involves downstream calculations that may benefit from sorting, then you should attempt to sort the input array once and early in the logic stream so that all functions re-use the same sorted instance.

If the time taken to sort and then execute your function is significantly less than if you executed the function with an unsorted array, then you could argue that there is a benefit to forcing your function to sort first.

The problem is that if your functions continually sort the same array instance that is already sorted, then there are some performance gains to be made by eliminating the sorts all together.

If your functions involve operations that will perform better with a sorted array, then you should specify that the input argument *is* a sorted array, (in c# you might use a `SortedList`) then you have declared to the caller that they are required to handle the sorting in advance.